# Can netatalk be configured to adhere to ACL's?

Tags: debian, access-control-list, debian-lenny, afp, netatalk

Is is possible, and if so how, to configure Netatalk to respect ACL's? I'm running Debian Lenny, with the ACL packaged installed.

ACL's work great using SSH, which is why I started using it. But, if I login via AFP, I can't access the files.

Answer (score 1):

They're working on it:  http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/2.2/ReleaseNotes2.2beta1.html

Comment: Looks like 2.2.1 has it now:  `POSIX draft 1e ACL support`.  http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/2.2/ReleaseNotes2.2.1.html